# Laravel 9: NotFoundHttpException when accessing routes despite correct .htaccess and virtual host configuration

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, localhost, virtualhost

I'm encountering a NotFoundHttpException error in Laravel 9 despite having what seems to be the correct .htaccess configuration and virtual host setup. Here are the details of my setup:

.htaccess inside the public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
    Header set X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
</IfModule>
```

Virtual Host Configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAlias *.afterhire.local
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html/afterhire/public/"

    <Directory "/var/www/html/afterhire/public/">
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Despite these configurations, when I try to access my any Laravel routes or its base url like 127.0.0.1:8000 or admin.afterhire.local, I encounter a NotFoundHttpException. What could be the possible reasons for this error, and how can I troubleshoot and resolve it?

Comment: If this was a 404 on the web server level, then you could hardly get a NotFoundHttpException from Laravel. So your request must have already made it "into" Laravel - but it know doesn't find a valid route for that request.

Comment: @CBroe isn't the problem with htaccess?

Comment: Don't think that's likely, no. Your `# Handle Front Controller...` part there is the standard, as far as I can tell. This doesn't rely on passing any additional URL parameters with the rewrite, Laravel will access the originally requested URL, and handle routing based on that. And, again, since you are getting an exception thrown _by_ Laravel, it must mean your request has already made it "into" Laravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than running your site trough a http server such as Apache, can you run it using `php artisan serve`.

If you get the same error then the issue will be in your `routes/web.php` or something further in the Kernal, Middleware etc.

Otherwise it'll be in your php config.
Check you have the required php modules enabled, including URL Rewrite.

If all these checks pass, the best suggestion I have is to start from a clean Laravel project, and copy over your code in chucks to see where you get the error.